# adding a physical node to azure scale set through UI

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

Is it possible to add a physical node to an azure scale set from azure web UI?
(not using powershell/visual studio/rest api..)

Comment: from portal only deallocating entire vmss is possible. powershell or CLI is the option at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the "capacity" of a scale set is not possible in the portal yet, but it's coming very soon, i.e. next few weeks.